# How to replace c-pointer with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++11

I am new to C++11 so please be nice.

Could you show me an easy example, how a shared_ptr can replace standard pointer? I also appreciate, an explanation if it does not make sense in that case.

e.g. Could you transform this code?

```
std::vector <CVariant*>liste;
liste.push_back( new CVariant( (unsigned int) 24, Parameter1", TYPE_UINT) );
std::cout << liste.at(0)->get<int>() <<"\n";
delete liste.at(0);
```

->

```
std::vector < std::shared_ptr<CVariant> >liste;
```

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you should do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CVariant>> liste;

liste.push_back( std::make_shared<CVariant> (arguments...));
```

Check this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/make_shared/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that works. You can also use the constructor of shared_ptr directly:

`liste.push_back(std::shared_ptr<CVariant>(new CVariant(arguments...)))`

Have a look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/

Answer (score 3):

If you have a vector list like this

```
std::vector < std::shared_ptr<CVariant> >liste;
```

You should call the `liste.push_back` method with shared pointer instead of pointers. You can initialize shared pointers in c like this:

```
auto pointer = std::make_shared<CVariant>( (unsigned int) 24, Parameter1", TYPE_UINT );
```

Ant add the pointer to the list like this:

```
liste.push_back( pointer );
```